# SPARQL ElementPathBlock

Tags: api, sparql, jena, arq

In am trying to retrieve the triples of a SPARQL expression involved in the `OPTIONAL` and `NON OPTIONAL` part of the query, separately.

I used the API ARQ Jena visitor but neither `ElementPathBlock` nor `ElementGroup` nor `ElementOptional` are enough. `ElementPathBlock` retrieves all the triples, and `ElementGroup` retrieves the groups of triples (enclosed by `{}`), and `ElementOptional` the optional `Elements`.

Could you help me please?

Comment: The SPARQL structure is hierarchical, i.e. elements are usually nested. That means, the OPTIONAL might be inside an `ElementGroup` etc. `ElementWalker` is probably the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I found the solution. I was using the ElementWalker as you suggested. However, ElementWalker is not useful (or I could not find the good way) for the traversal of a SPARQL query as usual, I means left-to-right and top-down traversal. I had to write my own method for the traversal of a SPARQL using instanceof, and each type of SPARQL expression: ElementPathBlock, ElementOptional, etc, and recursion.  In this way, I was able to extract the optional part (and mandatory part) of the query, as well as union and minus, etc.